# emacs tab width conflicts with auto-complete

Tags: emacs, ubuntu-11.04

I installed emacs auto-complete and put the following lines in ~/.emacs

```
; set the default tab width as 4
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)

; set the auto-complete
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d//ac-dict")
(ac-config-default)
```

The problems that I found is as follows:

```
int main(void)
{
  std:  :   
}
```

AS you can see, if I enter `std::`, the emacs automatically expands it as `std:  :`. If I remove the line `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)`, then the problem goes away so does the default tab width of `4`.

Is there a workaround that I can use to make both functions co-exist without problems.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Consider filing a bug report with the autocomplete author. Sounds like a simple bug.